# Iterating each line in a text file to set each line as a variable then looping through each variable in an Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, devops

At the moment I have a Powershell script which reads a text file with one user's name, sets it as a variable, then within my Azure pipeline I have some parameters that are overwritten with that user name to automate resource deployment that is tied to that name.

This works well with one name but once I introduce a second line/name into the text file (also happens with an Excel file) I get an error about a deployment parameter having an empty key.

Would I need to create a variable array for each name in the file then having my pipeline loop through each variable to verify if that name has resources tied to it?

I'm fairly new to Powershell and am wanting to learn about it so if anyone could guide me in the right direction first instead of giving the answer up front I would appreciate it.

The code below works with one name in the text file and can set the variable properly.

```
Install-Module ImportExcel -Scope CurrentUser -Force;$clientvar = Import-Excel $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/ClientTestListExcel.xlsx | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name;Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=clientname]$clientvar"
```

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'RgPStest'
    location: 'East US'
    overrideParameters: '-SQLname $(clientname) -DBname $(clientname) -blobstoragecontainer $(clientname) -clienttag $(clientname)'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @dugas Sorry about that, edited the original post with PS script task and ARM deployment tasks from my YAML.

Comment: Do you [create multiple instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources) of a resource in your arm template? If your parameter is `array` type in arm template, you also need to [override the parameter](https://alltechstuff.xyz/docs/vsts/azure/2018/08/27/vsts-azure-array-override-param.html) with a variable in the form of  `array`.